# Can't connect to MySQL server, No connection could be made because the tared machine actively refused it

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am trying to connect to a MySQL db on my ubuntu VPS with python and I am using this code

```
import pymysql

conn= pymysql.connect(host='remotehost',port='3306', 
user='user',password='password',db='db')

a = conn.cursor()

sql = 'SELECT * from `users`;'
a.execute(sql)

countrow = a.execute(sql)
print("Number of rows :",countrow)
data = a.fetchone()
print(data)
```

When I run the code I get the following error
    `pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'remotehost' ([WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)")`

I have checked my MySQL db and the 'user' that I am connecting to the server with has the "Any host" hostname set. I can't seem to fix this issue.

Comment: What about connecting from command line using `mysql -h ... -p ` ?

Comment: When trying to connect through command line I got the same error, Can't Connect to MySQL server <10061>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by commenting out 
`bind-address = 127.0.0.1` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`